# List of Doctrine2 Exceptions

Tags: exception, doctrine-orm

I am not able to find a list of all Doctrine2 exceptions in the Doctrine manual. Does anybody have such a list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found this:

```
Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Exception\CircularReferenceException
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException
Doctrine\Common\CommonException
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException
Doctrine\ORM\TransactionRequiredException
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\ASTException
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException
Doctrine\ORM\UnexpectedResultException
Doctrine\ORM\PessimisticLockException
Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\HydrationException
Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException
Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Export\ExportException
Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyException
Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException
Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException
Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryException
Doctrine\DBAL\Types\ConversionException
Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException
Doctrine\DBAL\Sharding\ShardingException
Doctrine\DBAL\ConnectionException
Doctrine\DBAL\Cache\CacheException
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\OCI8\OCI8Exception
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\SQLSrv\SQLSrvException
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\IBMDB2\DB2Exception
Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException
```

Comment: [Updated link](http://webdeveloper.gdemolished.com/list-of-symfony2-exceptions/) - Not sure of validity